# Why ist Magento 2.2 loading all entity type attributes in Magento\Eav\Model\Config

Tags: performance, magento, attributes, magento2, entity-attribute-value

I just ran into a problem: Why does Magento load all entity-type attributes in the Model

```
Magento\Eav\Model\Config.php?
```

I am facing a situation with many product-attributes (round about 20,000) and sets (almost 10,000) and the shop became very slow. Some debugging made clear, that in the named class (Magento\Eav\Model\Config.php) all entity-type attributes are loaded and stored in an array, the set is ignored. This makes the site really slow.

Why is magento loading all attributes here and not just the ones needed via attribute set? Hard-Coding the attribute set works on the product page. Wondering, if some registry solution could be made.

Thank in advance for your ideas and opinions.

**Edit**

Thank you for your replies. Here is the problem in more detail: On a product page, the function getEntityAttributes of the Config model is called twice. Once with the product object, which leads into loading the correct attribute set. The second time it is loaded just for the product entity type. That makes Magento load all product attributes and saves it into an array, which is very slow. The function getAttributes - for example - calls the function getEntityAttributes just by entitytype.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Cleaned up grammar, spelling and broke out path.